# Norm inequality proof

Tags: functional-analysis

How to show that for any normed space and for any two elements x and y, the following inequality holds: $||x|| \leq max \{||x+y||, ||x-y||\}$ ?

I believe that i need to show the following: 1) $||x|| > ||x+y|| => ||x|| \leq ||x-y||$ and 2) $||x|| > ||x-y|| => ||x|| \leq ||x+y||$, but I don't know how it can be done.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $x=\frac12\bigl((x+y)+(x-y)\bigr)$. By the triangle inequality,
$$\lVert x\rVert\le \frac12\bigl(\lVert x+y\rVert+\lVert x-y\rVert\bigr) \le \frac12\cdot 2\max\bigl(\lVert x+y\rVert,\lVert x-y\rVert\bigr).$$